# RPM: rpmbuild file not found

Tags: rpm, packaging, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to create a very simple RPM for my tar.gz.
Here's my files:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── RPMS
├── SOURCES
│   └── bpf-10_24_2018.tar.gz
├── SPECS
│   └── bpf.spec
└── SRPMS
```

and this is my bpf.spec:

```
# This is a spec file for BPF samples

%define _topdir     %(pwd)
%define name        bpf
%define release     0
%define version     10_24_2018
%define buildroot   %{_topdir}/%{name}-%{version}-root

BuildRoot:  %{buildroot}
Summary:        BPF samples
License:        -
Name:           %{name}
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Source:         %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
Prefix:         /usr
Group:          Verification/Tools

%description
The BPF samples test basic xdp functionality.

%prep
%setup -q
```

Basically I already compiled everything I need and put it inside the tar.gz, now I want to build the RPM for it. But I keep failing. Inside my tar.gz I have 3 files that I want to be available to execute after I install the RPM later(xdp1, xdp2 and xdp_redirect, all already executables), they're all present inside the tar.gz. I know I'm missing stuff in my spec but not sure what. I don't need to build or install anything so...

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the install and files sections; I cannot provide them exactly, because that depends on what is inside your tar.gz file, but it would look something like this:

```
%install
install -D -m 0755 path/in/tar/to/binary $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/bin/my-binary

%files
/usr/bin/my-binary
```

in the `install` sections you put all files in the correct structure under `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`; then in the `files` section you specify what files are effectively contained inside your final rpm.